# How to show a spinner while backbone view is rendering?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have to render a Backbone view with a lot of information, but I'd like to show an animation (spinner) while the information is rendering, can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 1):

Make a div that has a spinner, `show` it before you render your information, and `hide` it when you're done.

You can even grab some [css-only spinners](http://cssload.net/) with a simple google search, or use the [spin.js](http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/) javascript tool.

I'd need to see some code or know of a specific problem with what you're doing to give you better information.

Comment: He can wrap the render method like here http://www.sagarganatra.com/2013/01/adding-beforerender-and-afterrender-functions-to-backbone-view.html